# Преобразование типов

Tags: c#

Есть ситуация: присутсвует объект obj1, унаследованный от obj2, в obj1 есть свои родные поля. Как произвести каст его в obj2, чтоб при сериализации не учитывались поля obj1?

Пример:

```
class obj1 : obj2
{
 public VeryBadPropBrokeMySerialization bad{get; set;}
}

obj2
{
 public GoodProp good {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: А зачем Вам это? Если вы скастите к obj2, у Вас свойств и obj1 не будет для доступа.

Comment: Так так и надо. Подправил разметку примера, может, так будет понятней.

Comment: Я к тому, что какая разница, что будет сериализоваться, если вы, когда скастите к obj2, не будите иметь доступ к свойствам obj1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала, никаким преобразованием типов (кастом) вы не сможете повлиять на сериализацию: при сериализации учитывается лишь настоящий, runtime-тип.

Для решения вашей проблемы вам стоит попробовать использовать ручную сериализацию. Например, если речь идёт об XML-сериализации (вы не указали в вашем вопросе, о какой именно), вам нужно реализовать интерфейс [`IXmlSerializable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).